# Issue in retrieving core.json attributes from BinaryData folder

Tags: dxa, dxa-java

I'm trying to access the value in **core.json** file which is under `BinaryData` folder.
Below is the way I'm trying to retrieve the value:

`${requestScope.localization.getResource('core.keyname')}`

But application doesn't retrieve the latest value when it changed in the core Component. But changes are reflected in the `core.json`.

May I know what could be the issue?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you do get a value back, but it's not the latest data from the file? If so, it might simply be cached.

Comment: @PeterKjaer Thanks for your quick response. May i know where is the cache setup?

Answer (score 4):

As the json file is updated I assume you did a publish of the 'Publish Settings' Page.

Afterwards, you need to call the Admin Refresh endpoint `/admin/refresh` so that the website loads the new value. You do that by loading the `{WebsiteBaseUrl}/admin/refresh`  url in your browser, where WebsiteBaseUrl is the url of your website.

Comment: Yes, Even after i did the admin refresh, faced the same issue.